# Creating column divs in JS, but they are rendering as rows instead

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a Jeopardy game (following a tutorial)The code is throwing no errors but my JS div element header columns for my categories are not displaying in columns they display in rows as well as my clue boxes with not properly align into columns

I have my JS script at the bottom of my page, I have deconstructed and reconstructed the code to try and pinpoint my issue with no luck.

for a visual here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/NP27/pen/zYELarE

Code is as follows:

```
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="app">
    <header class="top-header">
        <h1>Trivia Game Show</h1>
        <p class="score">Score <span class="score-count"></span></p>
    </header>

    <!--container for the board-->
  <div class="board"></div> 
    <!--categories get injected here-->
```

CSS:

```
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;

    color: white;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #2e2e3a 0%, #0c0c2c 100%);

}
.top-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    text-shadow: var(--text-shadow);
}
```

JS Script :

```
renderCategory(category) {
    let column = document.createElement("div");
    column.classList.add("column");

    column.innerHTML = (
       `<header>${category.title}</header><ul></ul>`
    )
   

    this.boardElement.appendChild(column);
   

    
}
```

Comment: I suggest using `css grid` that you write 1 time in the parent for all :) so don't need to add the class for all (and is also responsive)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYMBkayHmUo&t=1343s this is the video I am following  and my intended look is at  time stamp  20:30.  what you did is kind of what I am looking for. It drives me nuts when Im trying to follow a tutorial and simple things don't work

Comment: So that is the layout I am looking for as far as  the top header categories, but shouldnt this also be making columns for my question boxes as well  after i append the column?

Comment: https://codepen.io/punkydrewster713/pen/dyXaOBZ   This is the codepen  for the original script I am following. the correct way its supposed to look like.

Comment: I don't know how to help you, sorry I will upvote so someone else can find this question easily.